# Can I get my data from my laptop

Tags: data-recovery

I have switched to Ubuntu and lost all my previous data how can I get it back? I had some issues in my laptop so I had to format it. So now without any backup, can I get back my data?

Comment: Usually once you format, it is very hard to get back that data. There are professionals who can partially recover the data. **Always keep a backup**. There's almost nothing we can do here. Have a look at the link posted by @lejurassien.

Comment: Stop using the computer now and boot from a live USB session. Use a separate USB storage device to store recovered files. Next, [you will probably use photorec (testdisk) or foremost to recover files that may exist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files). BTW, photorec recovers more than just photos. The content of the files may exist but the names of the files will not so you'll have to go through each recovered file. Sometimes, files are corrupted and may not be complete. See also: [Ubuntu help docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Answer (score 0):

when you value your data **a backup is essential**!!!
After a formatting and a filesystem change it's quite difficult to find some things, but if it's really important data there are always one or two programs to use...
I let you look here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Have a nice day and i hope you will recover your data !!

Comment: One to recommend is the testdisk suite. Good luck indeed. @ALPHA GAMING Keep your head cool as it can be very stressful to loose important data.